# Исчезает кнопка "Settings" в ListActivity

Tags: java, android

Почему то исчезла стандартная кнопка "Settings" в правом верхнем углу при использование ЛистВью. В чём проблема и как вернуть её обратно? Буду признателен.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
String[] Buttons = new String[100];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    for (int i=0;i<=99;i++){
        Buttons[i]=Integer.toString(i+1);
               }
    //    MyCustomAdapter forData= new MyCustomAdapter(this,Buttons);
        setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(this,Buttons));

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Toast.makeText(this, position + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: Проблем в коде не видно, за исключением того, что вам, очевидно, надо вынести назначение адаптера (`setListAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(this,Buttons));`) списку за пределы цикла.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб  Спасибо за замечание, но на кнопку Settings это не повлияло. При тестирование на реальном устройстве эта кнопка физическая, а вот и эмуляторе нажать никак

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте также переопределить метод `onPrepareOptionsMenu` и вернуть из него `true`:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

    return true;
}
```